# Relative path reference to XML file in XSLT does not find elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files containing elements in different languages. Their position in forders is the following:

[image: Structure in package explorer]

I want to load the value of certain  elements dynamically, according to the language that was previously selected and passed to the xsl document. Let's call it:

```
<xsl:variable name="messagebundle_lang">lang1.xml</xsl:variable>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="mainRoot">../xmlFiles/</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="string(concat($mainRoot, $messagebundle_lang))"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="document($root)/data/xml_element_1" />
```

This does work locally, but after deployment the elements that are loaded dynamically simply do not appear in the PDF that was generated based on **test.xsl**. I presume it is because of this:

```
../xmlFiles/
```

How could I include the path of the xml files? Can it be the problem of OS dependent path separator?

Comment: No, a URL always uses a slash .

Comment: Likely the document () function is blocked in your deployed environment as it is considered unsafe.

Comment: If I put the XML files in the directory xslFiles, it works. So I presume it has nothing to do with the document() function.